# How to turn on -mavx2 for only particular part of source code?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, intrinsics, avx2

Could I force compiler to compile some intrinsic functions outside `-march` setting in some particular part of code?

Of course, the rest would remain within `-march` setting.

Is it possible to enable `-mavx2` on only specific part of source code?

Or is the only way that I must compile `-mavx2` section separately?

Comment: Usually when I have a block of code with different compilation options, I put it in a different file and configure that one file to have the special options.

Comment: I thought there might be some syntactic sugar like `#pragma diagnostic push` / `pop` the warnings.

Comment: Could be, but few `pragma`s are portable between compilers. The relationship between GCC and clang is friendlier than most, so you might get lucky. I try to avoid luck. It just causes problems in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `__attribute__((target("avx2")))`. Both [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-target-function-attribute) and [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#target) support it.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

__attribute__((target("avx2")))
int add_with_avx2(int a, int b) {
    __m256i av = _mm256_set_epi32(a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    __m256i bv = _mm256_set_epi32(b, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    __m256i result = _mm256_add_epi32(av, bv);
    return ((int*)&result)[7];
}

int main(void) {
    return add_with_avx2(5, 6);
}
```

However, it's probably a better idea to put the functions that need intrinsics in a seperate file, in case you ever need to use a compiler that doesn't have this feature.

Comment: More importantly, a function can't inline into a caller with different target attributes (even with link-time optimization), so only use this on "large enough" functions, not single-vector helper functions.

Comment: @PeterCordes `can't inline into a caller with different target attributes` Why not lineable? That's such a bummer. Because we can protect user machine with `__get_cpuid()` by ourselves anyway. It's weird because not inlining-able like this seems not like C-style at all. This is kind of overprotective. What if I write with hand written asm block? Will they compile?

Comment: @sandthorn: It's a missed optimization that `if(supports_AVX2) { avx2_version(); }` can't inline.  Within a single function, gcc / clang doesn't know how to optimize while still making sure that no AVX2 instructions run *outside* of that condition.  e.g. if you had multiple `if(AVX2)` blocks, normal optimization might hoist a load out of them and do it before, for reuse across multiple blocks.

Comment: @sandthorn: you can't safely use `if (__get_cpuid(...) == ...) { some avx2 intrinsics; }` because you can only compile a function containing that if you use `-mavx2` or a target option.  So that gives the compiler freedom to use AVX2 instructions *anywhere* in the function.  The only way to get finer grained would be inline asm (the compiler doesn't know anything about what you put in inline asm, and the assembler doesn't do target-checking).

Comment: But don't actually use inline asm; **normally the right solution is to make separate versions of the function containing the long-running loop**, and dispatch to it via function pointers.  That makes sure that you're not branching on target options *inside* a tight loop.  This makes sure the compiler is able to fully optimize the whole function containing the whole hot loop for the target microarch you care about, e.g. Nehalem vs. Sandybridge vs. Haswell vs. Ryzen vs. Bulldozer vs. low-power Silvermont vs. baseline fallback with just SSE2 `tune=generic`

Comment: @PeterCordes `because you can only compile a function containing that if you use -mavx2` That's exact limitation point in my question. Why can't we expose some specific features only in certain lines of code?

Comment: @PeterCordes **"normally the right solution is to make separate versions of the function containing the long-running loop, , and dispatch to it via function pointers. That makes sure that you're not branching on target options inside a tight loop."** is such a very good general guideline. superb.

Comment: @sandthorn: Why? because gcc/clang have the limitation of only doing this at function granularity. Like I said this is normally totally fine and what you want anyway (to take target branching out of hot loops).  If you want to improve gcc by submitting a patch that lets it inline and optimize while keeping track of target options, go right ahead.  I expect it would be a huge amount of work, but sure maybe it would let GCC hoist an `if(AVX2)` out of a loop and let get efficient machine code from C source that "looks" really inefficient (with dispatch inside hot loops) instead of the normal way.

Comment: xD, oh you posted that "why?" question before reading my last comment where I described the existing efficient way.